# Sorting QGLSceneNodes to enable transparency

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transparency, qt3d

To enable transparency in our Qt3D-OpenGL-Scene, we implemented a QGLRenderOrderComparator to sort our scene based on the z-values. But the QGLRenderScequencer keeps to reorder our nodes (based on enabled shaders). Do you have an idea, how to prevent the reordering? Thanks!